# Laravel 4 - Not updating sessions

Tags: php, session, laravel-4

I am trying to achieve the following:

I am building a very basic shopping cart, if someone adds an item to the basket, this gets saved inside a session. I.e. `Session - array('id' => '1', 'quantity' => '1');` If they add another of these items with the same id, the product is not added again, but the quantity is adjusted with this.

My implementation:

```
$quantity = Session::get('basket_items2')[$product->id]['quantity'];
$newQuantity = (int)$quantity + 1;
$products[$product->id] = array("product_id" => $product->id, "quantity" => $newQuantity);
Session::put('basket_items2', $products);
```

However, the `quantity` just remains at 1 so no matter how many times you add the product, the quantity is always "2" therefore the session is not updating / overriding.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Try this way:- Session::push('basket_items2', $products);

Comment: @RaviHirani Nope. Still the same

Comment: Can you post var_dump($products);

Comment: Probably not related, but it would seem to me you are only getting 1 item from your cart / session and then overwrite the whole thing with only that item.